# Точное назначение свойств position и display в css

Tags: html, css

Может ли кто-нибудь доступно объяснить, как работают свойства `position` и `display` точно и понятно? Что именно обозначают `relative` и `absolute`, как их комбинировать и какого результата можно добиться?

Comment: Если знаете английский на среднем уровне советую посмотреть этот ролик. Очень чётко и ясное объяснение. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-vo0HzNHL3U

Comment: https://webref.ru/ вам сюда!!! для начала не атрибуты, а css свойства и их значения https://webref.ru/css/position

Comment: Чем документация в интернете недостаточно доступна?

Comment: MDN и вперед,изучать.